# Read 2 lines by 2lines in textfile

Tags: c#

Suppose that the method ReadUser below is reading the user and password in the textfile. The problem is, it doesn't read the rest of the textfile after reading the first 2 lines. How to solve this issue?

*Edit: how do I read first 2 lines then another 2 lines in the textfile ?

```
public override void ReadUser()
{
    user = base.UserID;
    password = base.Password;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Projects\\AdministratorModule//userTextFile.txt", FileMode.Open)))
    {
        user1 = sr.ReadLine();
        password1 = sr.ReadLine();
        sr.Close();

        if (user == user1 && password == password1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login Successfull");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are closing the StreamReader with sr.Close(); after reading the first 2 lines

Comment: @styx so i just need to remove sr.Close(), then it will continue reading the rest of the lines in the textfile?

Comment: See: [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines). Btw, having declared the `StreamReader` with a `using` statement, you don't need to close that stream. It's closed and disposed of as soon as you leave the `using` block. Also, this: `File.Open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Projects\\AdministratorModule//userTextFile.txt"` is a bad idea. Use the `Application.StartupPath` to access the directory where your application's executable is **currently** located (it won't be there when you deploy).

Comment: This code will only ever read the first two lines, regardless of where you call `Close()`. You're explicitly calling `sr.ReadLine();` twice, and that's it. In order to read all the lines from a file, you need to use a loop, or a method that reads all the lines.

Comment: @Jimi, any idea how to use application.startupPath?

Comment: `Application.StartupPath` is the path of your executable. If you're using the `Debug` profile, it's `[ProjectPath]\Bin\Debug`. If you're using the `Release` profile `[ProjectPath]\Bin\Release`. When you install or otherwise deploy your app, it's the path where your executable is installed/copied to. Move your file there. For now. After, you'll have to learn how to add a file to your project and use its properties to select `Copy to Output Directory`. You can choose `Always` or `If Newer`. What best fits your needs.

Comment: So, for example, your file path can be `string myFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "userTextFile.txt");`. The `Path` requires `using System.IO;`.

Comment: @Jimi alright, thanks sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple a basic logic

```
int currentLine = 0;
//no need use close method with using
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Projects\\AdministratorModule//userTextFile.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        switch (++currentLine)
        {
            case 1: user1 = line; break;
            case 2: password1 = line; break;
            case 3: otherVariable = line; break;
            case 4: yetAnotherVariable = line; break;
            ......
        }
        //rest of your logic

    }
}
```

However, if for some reason you need to store all the strings in an array, you're best off just using  [File.ReadAllLines();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Any idea about reading 2 lines from textfile then follow by another 2 lines in the textfile?? *sorry newbie here

Comment: @FatassBulky you can continue with this logic of using i variable (i corresponds to the line number that you are reading)

Comment: @FatassBulky edited my answer to give you a better understanding